# Column Space and Null Space as Subspaces

Tags: matrices

How do I know that the column space of the following matrix **IS NOT** a subspace of $R^4$?
I thought that the number of columns dictated the space (which would be $R^3$)

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 4 \\
6 & -4 & 2\\
-9 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

Similarly, how do I know what the null space of the same matrix **IS** a subspace of $R^4$?

Please use simple language. I have trouble understanding the rules of this section of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed column space of the given matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ and the nullspace is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. More in detail since columns are linearly independent, the rank is equal to $3$, the column space has dimension $3$ and the nullspace contains only the zero vector $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Omg I am dumb wait I just figured it out. Column space is subspace Rm and null space is space Rn. Thank you

Comment: By definition the nullspace is the space of the solutions to $Ax=0$ with $x\in\mathbb R^3$ according to the definition of matrix product.